# How to set environment variables only in the SYSTEM account

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-server, windows-services

I have a Windows Service running in Windows Server 2016 (under the SYSTEM account), and I need the service to access Web API credentials which should be stored in environment variables. I don't want them stored in the standard System environment variables, otherwise anyone with access to the server could see them. Can I store them so only the SYSTEM account has access, and if so, how?

Comment: Is the service only able to access credentials stored in environment variables? Could you pass the credentials using PowerShell? https://interworks.com/blog/trhymer/2013/07/08/powershell-how-encrypt-and-store-credentials-securely-use-automation-scripts/  Basically, we need to understand this service you're using a bit better in order to get you a good solution.

Comment: Here's some related questions: https://superuser.com/questions/1138214/protect-powershell-script-from-being-opened-edited-or-modifed-in-windows https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180243/best-practices-for-storing-credentials-used-by-code

Comment: Is the service written by you? If so, why did you _choose_ to use environment variables rather than simpler to secure mechanisms such as an ACL-protected txt/conf/json/etc file?

Comment: My service is a compiled .exe, written in .NET/C# - it is accessing Twilio APIs. Their recommended best security practices are storing the credentials in local env vars (as opposed to hard-coding the strings in the compiled code).

Comment: @grawity I guess your suggestion would be equivalent: a file which only SYSTEM has access to, which the service could read, or a file which only SYSTEM has access to, which will auto-load environment variables into the account space. The .NET API for accessing env vars is a little simpler than opening/parsing a file.

Comment: There are quite a few choices "as opposed to hard-coding the strings", and frankly environment variables are _not_ the best among them (neither on Windows nor on Linux). It confuses me that they're suggested so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution: In the registry, add a Value/Data pair to the key `\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Environment\` This will of course allow all local admins access (as would any "secure" solution), but that group in this case is trustworthy.